# Histogram with QWT in Microsoft Visual Studio and Qt addin which closes immediately

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, opencv, qwt

I am using Qt add in for Visual Studio C++ for my GUI.

And on my GUI, I have a button called the plotButton which will draw an histogram of the image when clicked. My plotting option is via the usage of QWT.

However, it does not seem to be plotting anything and closes almost immediately. Tried sleep(), but it doesn't seem to work either. Could the problem be with my code?
Here is my code for reference:

```
void qt5test1 ::on_plotButton_clicked()
{
    //Convert to grayscale
    cv::cvtColor(image, image, CV_BGR2GRAY);


    int histSize[1] = {256}; // number of bins
    float hranges[2] = {0.0, 255.0}; // min andax pixel value
    const float* ranges[1] = {hranges};
    int channels[1] = {0}; // only 1 channel used

    cv::MatND hist;
    // Compute histogram
    calcHist(&image, 1, channels, cv::Mat(), hist, 1, histSize, ranges);

    double minVal, maxVal;
    cv::minMaxLoc(hist, &minVal, &maxVal);//Locate max and min values

    QwtPlot plot; //Create plot widget
    plot.setTitle( "Plot Demo" ); //Name the plot
    plot.setCanvasBackground( Qt::black ); //Set the Background colour
    plot.setAxisScale( QwtPlot::yLeft, minVal, maxVal ); //Scale the y-axis
    plot.setAxisScale(QwtPlot::xBottom,0,255); //Scale the x-axis
    plot.insertLegend(new QwtLegend()); //Insert a legend

    QwtPlotCurve *curve = new QwtPlotCurve(); // Create a curve
    curve->setTitle("Count"); //Name the curve
    curve->setPen( Qt::white, 2);//Set colour and thickness for drawing the curve 
    //Use Antialiasing to improve plot render quality
    curve->setRenderHint( QwtPlotItem::RenderAntialiased, true );
    /*Insert the points that should be plotted on the graph in a 
    Vector of QPoints or a QPolgonF */
    QPolygonF points;
    for( int h = 0; h < histSize[0]; ++h) {
        float bin_value = hist.at<float>(h);
        points << QPointF((float)h, bin_value);
    }

    curve->setSamples( points ); //pass points to be drawn on the curve
    curve->attach( &plot ); // Attach curve to the plot 
    plot.resize( 600, 400 ); //Resize the plot
    plot.replot();
    plot.show(); //Show plot
    Sleep(100);
}
```

Upon clicking this button after loading the image, a window appear and disappear immediately. Under the output window, the lines can be found.

```
First-chance exception at 0x75d54b32 (KernelBase.dll) in qt5test1.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x0044939c..
Unhandled exception at 0x75d54b32 (KernelBase.dll) in qt5test1.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x0044939c..
```

Does anybody have any idea what could be wrong with my code? Thanks. Please note once again that the program is build, and written within Microsoft Visual Studio C++. Thanks.

Comment: if you are creating plot within the event scope, that might cause a problem. out of the scope, garbage collector cleans it. try declaring `QwtPlot *plot` in mainwindow.h, define it with the form load: plot = new QwtPlot(0); use it inside this event: plot->property->...

Comment: you also aren't inserting the plot to your ui. you should insert that in a layout, frame, etc... layout->addWidget(plot)

Comment: @C.CanberkBacı,Thanks. I will try it out later. And get back to you on the result

Comment: @berak, no worries (: Haha. But I just don't understand the guy who downvote my question. QWT does not have very good documentation. I dun understand why he downgrade it. I did try google and everything before posting on stackoverflow as always. Though it's a valid question. :/ Haha.

Comment: @rockinfresh try to post questions to Qt/Qwt forum http://www.qtcentre.org/forums/23-Qwt. If you are lucky enough, Uwe (founder of qwt) will answer your question in detail. Documentation could be just a doxygen-output but his support to the project should be acknowledged.

Comment: @rockinfresh one more thing to mention, if you ask questions related with c++ itself, not about your tags, you could be down-voted. For instance, here I see a garbaged stack variable; pointer issues etc. which are all related with lack of memory management.

Comment: Noted. Thanks for both advices. I will brush up my memory management knowledge as well(:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are constructing a stack object here:

```
QwtPlot plot; //Create plot widget
```

That is true that you are trying to show the plot at the end of the method, but the show() method is not blocking with an event loop like the QDialog classes when you use the exec() call on them.

It would be processed, but you are leaving the scope right after the call either way.

There are several ways of addressing this issue, but I would strive for the Qt parent/child hierarchy where the deletion will come automatically when using pointers.

1) Qt parent/child relation

```
QwtPlot *plot = new QwtPlot(this);
                            ^^^^
```

2) Make "plot" a class member

```
plot.show();
```

and construct it in the class constructor.

3) Use a smart pointer

```
QSharedPointer<QwtPlot> plot = QSharedPointer<QwtPlot>(new QwtPlot());
```

It depends on your further context of the class which way to pick up, so try to understand these approaches, and take your peek.

Comment: I don't quite understand what difference would it make if `show()` was blocking, since what would it block for? Until the first repaint was done? Even then, it wouldn't help at all, so **blocking-ness of `show()` is a red herring**. Anyway, `show` doesn't really use the event loop for most of its processing. Saying that it "posts an event to the event loop for execution" is technically true but **misleading**. If you inspect `QWidget` source, `postEvent` appears 5 times only. When a widget is shown, a LayoutRequest may get posted from `updateGeometry_helper`.

Comment: @KubaOber: OK, having rethought it, I made some modifications to be "less, but more". :-)

Comment: Thanks @Laszlo!! Always helping me with all my QWT queries so far(: Anyway, there will be a new error, C2664: 'QwtPlotItem::attach': cannot convert parameter 1 from 'QwtPlot **' to 'QwtPlot *'. Any idea? the error is found on this line of code: (curve->attach( &plot ); // Attach curve to the plot )

Comment: @rockinfresh: change it to `curve->attach(plot);` You do not need to request the address of a pointer when switching from a stack to heap object. That already contains an address.

Comment: Just realised that... Basic knowledge. Can't believe I didn't see that:/ Guess I need some sleep and brush up my programming skills again. Thanks though(:

Answer (score 1):

`plot` should be created using `new`. Now you create it on stack, so it will be deleted immediately when `on_plotButton_clicked` function finished. `Sleep` should not be used here, you won't get any good from it.

```
QwtPlot* plot = new QwtPlot();
plot->setTitle( "Plot Demo" ); //Name the plot
//...
plot->show(); //Show plot
```

Comment: if I use this method, there will be a new error, C2664: 'QwtPlotItem::attach': cannot convert parameter 1 from 'QwtPlot **' to 'QwtPlot *'. Any idea? the error is found on this line of code: (curve->attach( &plot ); // Attach curve to the plot )

Comment: You should use `attach(plot)` instead of `attach(&plot)` since `plot` is already a pointer.

Comment: Just realised that... Basic knowledge. Can't believe I didn't see that:/ Guess I need some sleep and brush up my programming skills again. Thanks though(: Really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be that your QwtPlot is just a local variable and even because the sleep is also in the main thread you won't be able to draw it in time before the function returns. Then when it finish sleeping it destroys your local QwtPlot object and returns, so you are luck enough if you get a blink of the window like that.

To make it work you will have to call it like this:

```
QwtPlot* plot = new QwtPlot(this);
```

where *this* is the parent window that will host your plot (if any). That way your widget will remain alive until you close it or its parent destroy it at the end of the program execution.

Comment: there will be a new error, C2664: 'QwtPlotItem::attach': cannot convert parameter 1 from 'QwtPlot **' to 'QwtPlot *'. Any idea? the error is found on this line of code: (curve->attach( &plot ); // Attach curve to the plot )